# URL issue in MVC5 using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to redirect to different page but somehow it is not working after publish. It is working fine in localhost.

The path I have publish is

```
https://dev.test.com/app/xfolder/app_name/...
```

View

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Add('@Model.Id')">Add</button>
```

js

```
function Add(id) {
        $.get("/XController/YAction/" + id, function(data){
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Url.Action` to construct your URL.

```
function Add(id) {
    $.get("@Url.Action("YAction", "XController")" + "/" + id, function(data){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but `Url.Action` doesn't work if I use this code in js file. Anyway I have found the alternatives.